# hide second div of a particular p tag using css

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to hide the second div after this div, there is no identifier for that `div`.

That's why I took this `p` tag attribute as an identifier. I tried using jQuery, but in page load it's sometimes visible. Is there any way to hide it permanently?

```
div p[data-udy-fe="text_-a91032"] {
    
}
```

I'm adding my jQuery code here, but when page loading we can see the `div`'s content for some seconds. I need to hide it permanently, without the brief flash.

```
$("p").each(function(){        
    if($(this).attr('data-udy-fe') == 'text_-a91032') {
        $(this).next('div').next('div').hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `+ div + div` selector

```css
p[data-udy-fe="text_-a91032"]+ div + div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>Paragraph1</div>
  <div>Paragraph2</div>
  <p data-udy-fe="text_-a91032">Paragraph3</p>
  <div>Paragraph4</div>
  <div>this one is not displayed</div>
  <div>Paragraph6</div>
<div>
```

Comment: You are Great, it's worked well.. <3 <3 ,Thank You so much <3 <3

Comment: No bother. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [general sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator) to select the p tag which occurs after your specific element.

```
div p[data-udy-fe="text_-a91032"] ~ p {
     display: none;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the attempt, i had to hide the second div next to the p tag,not the p tag element